# SQL-Как ввести одинаковые значения?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день всем.

Стоит такое задание, "Создайте таблицу, в которой будут записываться данные о учащихся, которые хотят изучать два или более предмета."[image: пример таблицы]

Как мне записать 2 и более значения для КодаФакультета? Через запятую не принимает. А КодСтудента не дублируется. 
Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: Если студент может посещать больше одного факультета, то связи между факультетами и студентами должны быть описаны отдельной таблицей.

Comment: И как это сделать примерно? Извините, я только начала работать в sql

Comment: создаете отдельную таблицу с двумя полями КодСтудента и КодФакультета. оба поля вместе являются первичным ключом такой таблицы. Из таблицы студентов поле кодФакультета удаляете (после того как перенесете данные в новую таблицу)

Comment: Я пробовала так, но записи все равно не дублируются(

Comment: Что значит "не дублируются", в отдельной таблице создаете две записи, если надо два факультета для одного студента, скажем КодСтудента=1, КодФакультета=1 и вторая запись КодСтудента=1, КодФакультета=2

Comment: Я сделала точно так же, выбивает ошибка. Вот скрин https://ibb.co/hpYQZc

Comment: А каким образом у вас в таблице оказались по несколько строк с одинним кодом студента и с NULL в факультете ? Первичный ключ не должен был позволить их сделать изначально. А ошибка говорит о том, что MS SQL не уверен, что вы меняете именно одну строку, потому что на таблице скорее всего нет первичного ключа

Comment: Спасибо большое, пересоздала таблицу, теперь все работает!